# XSL - only some lists are displayed

Tags: xml, list, xslt

I've been struggling with that problem for 2 days now, and I can't find the answer though I would believe I am close to it.

I have this (simplified) custom code :

```
<chapter><subchapter><subchaptersection><module>
            <topic>
                <title>Title1</title>
                <para>Para1.1</para>
                <list id="1">
                    <listitem>
                        <para>Item1.1</para>
                    </listitem>
                    <listitem>
                        <para>Item2.2</para>
                    </listitem>
                </list>

                <para>Para2</para>
                <list id="2">
                    <para>Para2.1</para>
                    <listitem>
                        <para>Item2.1</para>
                    </listitem>
                    <listitem>
                        <para>Item2.2</para>
                    </listitem>
                </list>
</subchaptersection></subchapter></chapter>
```

I have this XSL to transform custom code to partly XML (I have another XSL then to finish perfect conversion to XML, and for your information, lists can also be present in "subchapter" sections) :

```
<xsl:template match="chapter"><Chapter><title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
<xsl:apply-templates select="module/topic|subchapter"/>
</Chapter>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="module/topic">

        <topic><xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(title)"/>
        </xsl:attribute><title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>

        <body><xsl:apply-templates select="para|*/para|warning//para|list/listitem/para|introduction//para"/>
        </body></topic>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subchapter">

        <topic><xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(title)"/>
        </xsl:attribute><title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>

        <body><xsl:apply-templates select="introduction//para|subchaptersection|module/topic"/>
        </body></topic>

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="subchaptersection">
        <topic><xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(title)"/>
        </xsl:attribute><title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="introduction//para|module/topic"/></topic>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="para|*/para|warning//para|list/listitem/para|introduction//para">

    <xsl:if test="not(ancestor::list) and not (ancestor::warning)">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
    </xsl:if> 

    <xsl:if test="ancestor::list">
    <xsl:call-template name="LIST"/>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="LIST">
    <xsl:if test="not (../preceding-sibling::listitem/para)">
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::listitem">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
    </xsl:if>
    <ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="self::para/following-sibling::listitem">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem I get is that list 2 is displayed but list 1 is not (only empty ul is output). From the several other lists, I could observe that **only lists containing a para between list and first listitem are displayed** (as it is the case with list 2).

Where did I make something wrong in my XSL ? I could always manually insert a para between list and first listitem, but I'm sure there is an XSL solution.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: I believe you're making a mistake by not having a template matching `list` and applying it. Instead you call a named template to handle a `list` from the context of its preceding sibling `para`. This adds horrible complexity to your code.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, I have managed to make it work thanks to your advice.
I have created list template linked to subchapter and module/topic sections. It simplified my list template :
 `<xsl:template match="list">
        <xsl:if test="para[parent::list]">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="para[parent::list]"/></p>
        </xsl:if>
        <ul>
  <xsl:for-each select="listitem[parent::list]">
            <li>
              <xsl:for-each select="./para"><p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p></xsl:for-each>
            </li>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: Frost, typing XML inside comments is quite unreadable... I have turned your XML into an answer. Please note that you can answer your own questions at StackOverflow, if you found a solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this question was answered by [Michael's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516611/xsl-only-some-lists-are-displayed#comment52892957_32516611) and the work of the OP, by using:

```
<xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:if test="para[parent::list]">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="para[parent::list]" />
        </p>
    </xsl:if>
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="listitem[parent::list]">
            <li>
                <xsl:for-each select="./para">
                    <p>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```